# Adding commas to sql values using php explicitly

Tags: php, sql, dynamic

My html looks like this

```
<h2>$<?php echo $final; ?></h2>
```

The page will dynamically spit out the value which is from a sql table. The value is set as an integer in the table.

The output looks something like this

$46000

How can i have a comma automatically inserted to look like:

$46,000

I would like to accomplish this using PHP.

Comment: Use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: can be done in the db query if that's more convenient

Comment: Edited my answer to show you how to do it in sql as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to a comment that this can be done in sql.

**MySQL**

Use [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_format).

For an integer:

```
SELECT FORMAT(Field, 0);
```

The second flag is how many numbers after the decimal you want.

For a float with 2 decimal points

```
SELECT FORMAT(Field, 2);
```

**PHP**

This can be accomplished using [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

From http://php.net/

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

To enhance this, number_format tends to do some rounding. So you may want something better if you have floats (but maybe you don't, but if you do) ::

```
$final = 46000.12;
echo number_format( floor( $final*100 ) / 100, 2 );
```

[Dagon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557846/dagon) makes a good point that you could also look into [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

From http://php.net/

```
$number = 1234.56;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56
```

Comment: for money its often better to use [money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) then its easy to internationalise if needed

Comment: @Dagon - Good point. Added for future visitors

Answer (score 2):

Use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).
To output `46000` as `46,000`, you need:

```
echo number_format(46000);
//46,000
```